# How to regrouping overlapped data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data set in an excel spreadsheet, I can know from it that, for example, Amy took drug B from day 11 to day 50, drug C from day 41 to day 50, drug F from day 51 to day 60.

[image]

However, I don't want the days to have overlap. I want to convert it to the following data set, which indicates that Amy took drug B from day 11 to day 40, drugs B and C from day 41 to 50, and drug F from day 51 to 60.

[image]

I am also interested in converting the dataset into the following form (if it is easier to do so), which tells us Amy took a mixture of different drugs from day 41 to day 50, without telling you she was actually taking drugs B and C at this period.

[image]

Suppose I have a very big set of data so that there is little hopes to convert the data manually, is there a convenient way to do this converting using excel? And if it is not possible to do this using excel, could anyone suggest me the right thing I should use.
Thank you in advance!

PS: The following is my initial dataset.

```
Subject        Drug type    Start day             End day

Peter              A            1                   20

Peter              B           41                   60

Peter              C           11                   40 

Peter              D           31                   40

Peter              E           51                   60

Amy                B           11                   50

Amy                C           41                   50

Amy                F           51                   60

Tom                A           11                   20

Kitty              B           11                   20

Kitty              C           21                   30
```

Comment: Use VBA. Load your data into the array, process it and store back.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for reminding, it should be ok now

Comment: You can also do this in Power Query